# How do I remove logs from console.log in ionic?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, console.log

I wish to now build and distribute the app built with Ionic.
However, re-initialising `console.log()`'s is not producing the desired effect.

I have tried to reinit console.log function but there are still logs in my application.

```
var console = {};
console.log = function(){};
window.console = console;
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I tested the code posted above and works on desktop : chrome, ff and IE http://jsfiddle.net/6Lbx71x4/

Comment: If you are minify your js before building app then it will remove all console log before building app. Otherwise you need to use some task runner like Gulp or Grunt to remove all console logs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Gulp** to accomplish this.

[gulp-strip-debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-strip-debug) is a gulp plugin which strips all console.log()'s, console.info(), debugger,... statements.

Here's an example how your `gulpfile.js` should look like:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var stripDebug = require('gulp-strip-debug');

gulp.task('strip-debug', function () {
    // Build location folder
    // Strip stuff in these files.
    return gulp.src('src/js/*')
        .pipe(stripDebug())
        // Location output of the 'stripped' files
        // In your case, this should be the same as your build destination
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js/'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to remove the cordova console plugin before publishing.

```
$ cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-console
```

reference: http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html